# Linux Kernel: What is the mapping of block device sectors to memory pages in struct bio?

Tags: linux-kernel, block-device, device-mapper

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel version 5.4.0). I am building a custom device mapper in which I want to cache the read data to a kernel space memory buffer so to serve later reads (similar to a page cache, but in the granularity of block device sectors). In order to do so, I need a mapping from `sector_t` (block device sector #) to the data.

From my understanding, I should be able to get this information from `struct bio` defined in `linux/blk_types.h`. I am referring to this pretty old [post](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/kerneldevelopment/0672327201/ch13lev1sec3.html). If I understand it correctly, `sector_t bi_sector` specifies where to read the data in the block device and the data is read into `struct bio_vec *bi_io_vec`, but how should I know which portion of the data is mapped to which sector? I have some guessing and I need to check if my understanding is correct.

To be more specific, there is only one `bi_sector` specified in `struct bio`, but each `bio` can have read size larger than 512B (the sector size). Does this mean `bi_sector` is the start sector number of a group of continuous sectors to read from?

Also, how is the read data stored in `bi_io_vec`? Is it also a linear mapping? by linear mapping, I mean, say, I read 4KB of data, and there are two segments (`struct bio_vec`) in `bi_io_vec`, then is the data stored in the memory region `(bi_io_vec[0].bv_page + bi_io_vec[0].bv_offset, bi_io_vec[0].bv_page + bi_io_vec[0].bv_offset + bi_io_vec[0].bv_len)` and `(bi_io_vec[1].bv_page + bi_io_vec[1].bv_offset, bi_io_vec[1].bv_page + bi_io_vec[1].bv_offset + bi_io_vec[1].bv_len)` in order?

Also, I order to read get the data from `bio`, is it not safe to use `char *bio_data(struct bio *bio)`? Should I iterate each `bio_vec` and gather the data?

Thanks!

Comment: "*I need a mapping from ... to the data*" -- The "*data*" is simply the contents of those sectors or logical blocks. There's already a "*mapping*" for this using the sector number or LBA. "*If I understand it correctly ...*" -- Since you stated that you're using kernel v5.4.0, you need to actually look at how `struct bio` is defined in that version. Otherwise the answers to your questions could be satisfied by understanding the keyword mentioned in that link that you seem to have overlooked: *scatter-gather I/O* (which involves a multi-sector disk operation to/from multiple memory buffers).

Comment: That post is ancient.  The entire I/O stack has been rewritten since then.  Current bio is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/blk_types.h#L262